# Typesetting "Na(+)/Cl(-)-dependent"

Tags: typography, chemistry

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
Na\textsuperscript{+}/Cl\textsuperscript{-}-dependent
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't really like the spacing between + and /. 
I would like to improve the look of this term, as is occurs quite a few times in my text. Do you have suggestions, please? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `chemformula` or similar package (`mhchem`, for instance) for the chemical formulas and `\negthinspace` for filling the hole. Such “visual” adjustment cannot generally be taken care of automatically, because they depend on relative shapes of the symbols next to each other.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{Na+}\negthinspace/\ch{Cl-}-dependent

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a weird argument to make because it's essentially kerning, which *is* taken care of automatically with a good font. Not for all pairs, of course, but there's nothing really preventing kerning to work here in theory, I think.

Comment: @Joey If you are able to get the superscript plus and the slash from the same font, then you can have kerning.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, beside the spacing problems, there are no good solution to typeset `Na⁺/Cl⁻-dependent` since the minus (always in math mode) followed for a hyphen is inherently unsightly in any position, but specially when the superscripts are too big, too low or the hyphen is too distant of the "l" character. One option to consider is  `\ominus` instead of minus sign because is easily distinguishable of hyphens. Anyway, my suggestion is to make `Na⁺/Cl⁻` as compact as possible so that the whole `Na⁺/Cl⁻-dependent` text could be regarded as one compound word. Some like that:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip.5em
\usepackage{lmodern}
\def\kion#1{\rlap{\raisebox{1.25ex}{\kern-.2em\fontsize{3}{0}\selectfont{$#1$}}}}
\def\ion#1{\rlap{\raisebox{1.25ex}{\fontsize{3}{0}\selectfont{$#1$}}}}
\begin{document}
Na\textsuperscript{+}/Cl\textsuperscript{-}-dependent\par 
Na\kion+/\kern-.1em Cl\ion--dependent\par
Na\kion\oplus/\kern-.1em Cl\ion\ominus-dependent  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem of the two solutions you propose is that one doesn't know in which order to read it. Also, the signs are way too small IMHO...

Comment: The first Cl- is wrong: the symbol is not a minus but a hyphen.

Comment: @clemens I know! the first line is just the code of the MWE in the question, just for comparison.

Comment: @yo' Do you mean read `Cl minus hyphen` vs `Cl hyphen minus` ? May be is better without overlapping horizontally, but then  `-dependent` "seem" not linked.  What is worse? As I said, I think that there are no a good solution for this.  On the other hand, the size of the symbols is still nearly the width of a hyphen and are intentionally tiny to obtain a more "compact" aspect, but this mainly a matter of taste, so I cannot argue anything against a bigger symbol.